# JqGrid, change width form editing

Tags: jqgrid

I have a JqGrid with the form editing option. 
When I click on add or edit, the dialog box appear but the width take all my screen. What I want is to set a specific width. I've tried to use the width attribute but it didn't work.

```
        $('#jqgCompLine').jqGrid('navGrid', '#jqgpCompLine',
            { add: true, del: true, edit: true, search: false },
            { width: '100px', url: '@Url.Action("Update")', closeOnEscape: true,
                beforeShowForm: function (form) {
                    $('#tr_TrC', form).attr('disabled', true);
                    $('#tr_All', form).attr('disabled', true);
                    $('#tr_Pe', form).attr('disabled', true);
                },
                beforeInitData: function () {
                    $("#jqgCompLine").setColProp('Cur', { formoptions: { label: 'Currency'} });
                    $("#jqgCompLine").setColProp('FCur', { formoptions: { label: 'Converted Currency'} });
                }
            },
```

Did I miss something?

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [width](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties) property should be a number. You should replace `width: '100px'` with `width: 100`

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg, it' so dumb but it took me almost 1h00 of research.